# TCL Is there any way to?

Tags: linux, ftp, tcl, adhoc, proc

Is there any way to do some procedure and don't do like this:

```
set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n(0) $tcp
$ns attach-agent $n(1) $sink
$ns connect $tcp $sink
set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $tcp
$ns at 1.0 "$ftp start" 
$ns at 130.0 "$ftp stop" 
##################################################################
set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n(6) $tcp
$ns attach-agent $n(15) $sink
$ns connect $tcp $sink
set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $tcp
$ns at 10.0 "$ftp start" 
$ns at 110.0 "$ftp stop" 
##################################################################
set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns attach-agent $n(8) $tcp
$ns attach-agent $n(0) $sink
$ns connect $tcp $sink
set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $tcp
$ns at 30.0 "$ftp start" 
$ns at 100.0 "$ftp stop"
```

over and over?
I do something like this:

```
    proc wymiana {ns n_varname w1 w2 t1 t2} {
    upvar 1 $n_varname n

    set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
    set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
    $ns attach-agent $n($w1) $tcp
    $ns attach-agent $n($w2) $sink
    $ns connect $tcp $sink
    set ftp [new Application/FTP]
    $ftp attach-agent $tcp
    $ns at t1 "$ftp start" 
    $ns at t2 "$ftp stop" 
}

wymiana $ns  n  1 2 1.0 100.0
```

But it doesn't work... In NAM there is no transmission. I don't know why. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instinct that there ought to be a better way is correct. What you need are a few tweaks:

```
proc wymiana {ns n_varname w1 w2 t1 t2} {
    upvar 1 $n_varname node

    set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
    set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
    ### Varname is different just to make it clearer
    $ns attach-agent $node($w1) $tcp
    $ns attach-agent $node($w2) $sink
    $ns connect $tcp $sink
    set ftp [new Application/FTP]
    $ftp attach-agent $tcp
    ### Changes on two lines below
    $ns at $t1 "$ftp start" 
    $ns at $t2 "$ftp stop" 
}

# Create the setup from your question
wymiana $ns  n  1  2   1.0 130.0
wymiana $ns  n  6 15  10.0 110.0
wymiana $ns  n  8  0  30.0 100.0
```

However, it's also reasonable to consider whether the simulation and node mapping are true globals and also what sort of syntax your procedure *ought* to take for clarity:

```
proc SetupFTP args {
    global ns n
    array set a $args

    set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno]
    set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
    $ns attach-agent $n($a(-from)) $tcp
    $ns attach-agent $n($a(-to)) $sink
    $ns connect $tcp $sink
    set ftp [new Application/FTP]
    $ftp attach-agent $tcp
    $ns at $a(-start) "$ftp start" 
    $ns at $a(-stop) "$ftp stop" 
}

SetupFTP -from 1 -to  2 -start  1.0 -stop 130.0
SetupFTP -from 6 -to 15 -start 10.0 -stop 110.0
SetupFTP -from 8 -to  0 -start 30.0 -stop 100.0
```

It's a total cheaty-hack doing it like this, and you can see that the implementation code is *very* similar, but this way of doing it is going to look much clearer when you come back to the code. (You can also set defaults by doing `array set a {the-default mappings}` first thing in the procedure, and you can add more error checking. Or not. It's up to you. I've no idea what sensible default values might be; I suppose the types of agents might be good for that sort of thing.)

Comment: As far as I can see from quickly scanning the documentation, the names of the variables are pretty much arbitrary, ordinary Tcl variables; the ns2 engine just cares about the values in them. Which means you can use all sorts of tricks to make things nice to work with!